# What is the diff between declaring a Stream with try-with-resources statement or not?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, Stream (which is AutoCloseable) cannot be reused, once it is consumed or used, the stream will be closed. So what is the utility to declared with try-with-resources statement ?

Example with try-with-resources statement :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (Stream<Path> entries
            = Files.walk(Paths.get("."), 4, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
        entries.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toAbsolutePath()));// the entries stream will be automatically closed at this point
        //..
        System.out.println("Still in the Try Block");
    } //The entries will be closed again because it is declared in the try-with-resources statement
}
```

And here the same example without the try catch block

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Stream<Path> entries = Files.walk(Paths.get("."), 4, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
        entries.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toAbsolutePath()));// the entries stream will be automatically closed at this point
        System.out.println("Is there a risk of resources leak ?");
    }
```

Which one is safer ?

After some answers I update my code to check if the stream has been closed or not:

Here the new code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    resourceWithTry();
    resourceWithoutTry();
}

private static void resourceWithTry() throws IOException {
    try (Stream<Path> entries
            = Files.walk(Paths.get("."), 4, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).onClose(() -> System.out.println("The Stream is closed"))) {
        entries.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toAbsolutePath()));// the entries stream will be not automatically closed at this point
        System.out.println("Still in the Try Block");
    } //The entries will be closed again because it is declared in the try-with-resources statement
}

private static void resourceWithoutTry() throws IOException {
    Stream<Path> entries
            = Files.walk(Paths.get("."), 4, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).onClose(() -> System.out.println("Without Try: The Stream is closed"));
    entries.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toAbsolutePath()));// the entries stream will be not automatically closed at this point
    System.out.println("Still in the Try Block");
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In Java 8, Stream (which is AutoCloseable) cannot be reused, once it
>   is consumed or used, the stream will be closed.

Not exactly.
`Stream` terminal operations such as `forEach()` don't close the stream.
It makes the stream pipeline not consumable any longer.
Which is different.

[`Package java.util.stream` description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) states :

> After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is
>   considered consumed, and can no longer be used; if you need to
>   traverse the same data source again, you must return to the data
>   source to get a new stream.

It doesn't say that the stream is closed.

So in the following code, the `AutoCloseable.close()` method of the `Stream` instance is never invoked :

```
Stream<Path> entries = Files.walk(Paths.get("."), 4, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
entries.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toAbsolutePath()));
```

---

So is it always required to close the stream ? (with explicit `close()` invocation or better `try-with-resources`)

`java.util.stream.Stream<T>` javadocs explains that nearly all `Stream` instances don't need to be closed with `AutoCloseable.close()` after using. 
It is only true for IO stream.

> Streams have a close() method and implement AutoCloseable, but nearly
>   all stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use.
>   Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those
>   returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing. Most
>   streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions,
>   which require no special resource management. (If a stream does
>   require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a
>   try-with-resources statement.)

In our case, you manipulate `File`s, so it makes sense to close the channel. 
By using a `try-with-resources`, you avoid resource exhaustion exceptions and errors that may occur.
If any error or exception is risen during the processing, the resource may be all the same released.

Comment: I updated my post and I added a new code to check if the stream is closed or not ofter that have been consumed and you have right. Thank you

Comment: To be more precise, in both cases (IO or Collection Stream) , in the method invocation case as in your example, the stream instances will be **purged**  after the method return (it is not really specific to a GC action. Method invocations work on the stack that is discarded after return). And whatever an exception is thrown or not during the method, the local variables on the stack are purged. (1/2)

Comment: The difference between them is that streams that use resources(IO) invoke methods that may lock files or maintain a connection, etc.... So, in this specific case, as the method that manipulates resources returns, you will be sure that you removed all potential locks on these closeable resources.(2/2)

Answer (score 7):

The stream processing may get interrupted, and then it will not be fully consumed and it will not get automatically closed.
Consider this example:

```
Stream<Integer> nums = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
nums.onClose(() -> System.out.println("close was called"));
nums.forEach(x -> { if (x > 1) throw new IllegalStateException(); });
```

This will crash in the middle, and the `onClose` will not get called.
The stream remains open and you must close it manually.

If you use *try-with-resources* it will get correctly closed, no matter what,
as you can observe:

```
try (Stream<Integer> nums = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)) {
    nums.onClose(() -> System.out.println("close was called"));
    nums.forEach(x -> { if (x > 1) throw new IllegalStateException(); });
}
```

This is a tortured example,
since it doesn't consume any resources that would need to be closed,
the garbage collectors will clean up,
even though the stream was not closed.

> So what is the utility to declared with try-with-resources statement ?

It ensures that the stream gets closed no matter what.
When the stream is not backed by resources that would need to get closed,
it doesn't actually matter.

The example above was just to demonstrate the difference,
but in such code it's unnecessary paranoia to use try-with-resources,
just noise in the code, so it's actually better without the try-with-resources.

Comment: I updated my post to see if the stream has been automatically closed (see resourceWithoutTry()  method) and it seems that my stream still open !

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether your consumer throws an exception or not, `forEach` will never close the stream. Besides that, you should always use the return values of the stream methods instead of assuming that the method modified the stream’s internal state. Or just use chaining, which intrinsically uses the return value: `Stream.of(1, 2, 3) .onClose(() -> System.out.println("close was called")) .forEach(x-> { /* no need for throw*/ }); // will never print the message`…

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-), yes it is recommended (and safer) to close the stream returned in this instance using try-with-resources:

> If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the
>   try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the
>   stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are
>   completed.

In other cases, where the `Stream` is fed from an array or a list, it makes no difference.