# Use try-with-resources or close this 'Stream' in a "finally" clause

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, try-catch-finally, try-with-resources

I am using `Files.walk()` to get some files from directory stuff but I am getting a warning about blocker bug from Sonarqube and Sonarlint code analysis that

> Connections, streams, files, and other classes that implement the Closeable interface or its super-interface, AutoCloseable, needs to be closed after use. Further, that close call must be made in a finally block otherwise an exception could keep the call from being made. Preferably, when class implements AutoCloseable, resource should be created using "try-with-resources" pattern and will be closed automatically.

Here is the code:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(ifRecordsPath))
        .filter(Files::isDirectory)
        .map(ifRecordsCollector)
        .map(ifRecordStreamAccumulator)
        .forEach(ifRecordCollection::addAll);

return ifRecordCollection;
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108164/what-is-the-diff-between-declaring-a-stream-with-try-with-resources-statement-or) and almost got the problem but I do not know how exactly I stop the stream in correct place. When I add the finally block, it is still giving the same error

```
try {
    Files.walk(Paths.get(ifRecordsPath))
            .filter(Files::isDirectory)
            .map(ifRecordsCollector)
            .map(ifRecordStreamAccumulator)
            .forEach(ifRecordCollection::addAll);
} finally {
    Files.walk(Paths.get(ifRecordsPath)).close();
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: A method call is not a variable!  If you call `Files.walk(Paths.get(ifRecordsPath))` twice, you are creating two different Streams.

Comment: Your code creates a **new** stream in the finally to close, you need to close the original stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it meant is that you need to save the stream to a variable and then use it in a try-with-resources or close it in a try-finally. So either this:

```java
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(ifRecordsPath))) {
    paths.filter(Files::isDirectory)
        .map(ifRecordsCollector)
        .map(ifRecordStreamAccumulator)
        .forEach(ifRecordCollection::addAll);
    return ifRecordCollection;
}
```

Or this:

```java
Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(ifRecordsPath));
try {
    paths.filter(Files::isDirectory)
        .map(ifRecordsCollector)
        .map(ifRecordStreamAccumulator)
        .forEach(ifRecordCollection::addAll);
    return ifRecordCollection;
} finally {
    paths.close();
}
```

Comment: What if we want to return the open Stream?

Comment: @FlorianF If you want to return a open stream, then you just don't have to call `close()` on it, and also don't call a [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688418/what-is-the-difference-between-intermediate-and-terminal-operations) operation on it. If you still get a sonar error then I suggest you to just ignore it either implicitly (by not doing anything) or explicitly using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation (or closing the sonar issue as a false-positive on your sonar-tracker).